# Android layout design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am developing app where i want circuler image. it will rotate as songs play. 
can anyone help me to develop this layout.

[image]

Comment: please ref this link: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4218

Comment: Yes its work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to rotate your image view

```
musicDisc = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.musicDisc);
rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
musicDisc.startAnimation(rotation);
```

For stoping you can use clear animation

```
musicDisc.clearAnimation()
```

Rotating.xml
Keep in res folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Comment: Let me know . Aftr you run it

Comment: hi i use this link for my issue  link: android-arsenal.com/details/1/4218 - suggested in above comment by  Damini Mehra . anyways. this is also help for my another templet.